# std::vector references being copied on .insert()

Tags: c++, stl

I was trying out this code, but something that keeps happening is that when I insert into the vector the reference isn't changing. For example on the first insert into the vector all 11 elements will be equally changed including temp_word. Is this expected behaviour?

```
std::cout << "Searching for the top 10 scrabble scores" << std::endl;
Word temp_word;
std::vector<std::pair<Word&, unsigned>> word_scores;
for(unsigned x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
    word_scores.push_back({temp_word, 0});
for(Word& word : dict.words()){
    auto score = word.CalculateScrabbleScore();
    for(unsigned x = 0; x < 10; ++x){
        if(word_scores[x].second <= score){
            // Insert into the list of scores
            word_scores.insert(word_scores.begin() + x, {word , score});
            // Remove what was pushed off the list
            word_scores.erase(word_scores.begin() + 10);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::partial_sort` may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an `std::pair` contains a member of reference type, there's a very noticeable difference between its copy constructor and its assignment operator. Consider:

```
int n = 42;
std::pair<int&, int> p1{n, 0};
std::pair<int&, int> p2(p1);
assert(&p1.first == &p2.first);
```

Both `p1.first` and `p2.first` now refer to `n`. Compare and contrast:

```
int n = 42;
std::pair<int&, int> p1{n, 0};
int m = 84;
std::pair<int&, int> p2{m, 0};
p2 = p1;
assert(m == n);
```

`p1.first` still refers to `n`, `p2.first` still refers to `m`, but now `m` has the same value as `n`.

A reference is bound when initialized, and cannot be rebound afterwards. Assignment to a reference actually assigns to the underlying object.

`vector::insert` may legally use copy constructors, assignment operators or any combination of the two to move elements around. What happens in your example is that `vector::insert` first shifts elements out of the way (likely by assignment, but that doesn't really matter), then assigns to the "empty" spot. But that spot isn't really empty - it still holds its original element. It is during this assignment that `temp_word` gets modified, in the same way `m` gets modified by `p2 = p1;` in my earlier example.